# Translating SQL statement with dates to Linq-to-Sql for use with EF4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I have the following SQL command:

```
SELECT        CONVERT(varchar, Logged, 103) AS Visited, COUNT(ID) AS Totals
FROM            tblStats
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, Logged, 103)
ORDER BY Visited DESC
```

I want to translate this into a L2S statement that can be used with the Entity Framework, but in working with datetime types, I'm getting various errors depending on how I try to attack the problem.

Approach:

```
var results = from s in db.Stats
      group s by (s.Logged.Date.ToString()) into Grp
      select new { Day = Grp.Key, Total = Grp.Count() };
```

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.String ToString()'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Approach:

```
var results = from s in db.Stats
              group s by (s.Logged.Date) into Grp
              select new { Day = Grp.Key, Total = Grp.Count() };
```

Error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

What syntax do I need to make the query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method:

```
var results = from s in db.Stats
              group s by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Logged) into Grp
              select new { Day = Grp.Key, Total = Grp.Count() };
```

Comment: That's the problem!  Thanks.  Now I have a different issue, but I'll set up a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `Date` section in  `s.Logged.Date`?

Have you tried this:

```
var results = from s in db.Stats
              group s by (s.Logged) into Grp
              select new { Day = Grp.Key, Total = Grp.Count() };
```

I'm assuming that `Logged` is the property (column in the table).

EDIT: you guys are way to quick.

Comment: If you don't use the `Date` part then you will group by the full datetime, including the time component.